# How to make a list that won't add and element already on the list?

Tags: python

```
user=True

while user: 
    userName=input("Player Name:")
    names = []
    if userName in names: 
        print("Lets play again")
    else:
        print("Lets play")
        names.append(userName)
```

here's my code I basically want to make a list of names but if that name is already there then I don't want it to be added.

Comment: please format your code with backticks

Comment: Do you need to maintain the order of elements in the list?

Answer (score 2):

Use a [set](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#sets) instead of a list, sets don't allow duplicate values.

> note: don't initialize set as {}, it initializes a `dict`, you instead need to use `set()` for initialization.

you can start a set with values as :  `{"name1", "name2"}`.

```
names = set()
names.add("batman")
names.add("robin")
```

```
names = {"batman", "robin"}
```

Answer (score 1):

What you want is a python set, which acts as a list but only allows unique elements. It's also faster if you want to check if an element is in the set but that's outside the scope of this question.

Instead, you can write this:

```py
user=True

while user: 
    userName=input("Player Name:")
    names = set()
    if userName in names:
        print("Lets play again")
    else:
        print("Lets play")
        names.add(userName)
```